# Regex to find Href value

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string in which I have anchor tag I want to know the href values of those anchor tags.
my string is like:

```
This is Test page <a href='test.aspx'>test page</a> .
```

in this I want to find the value of href i.e. **test.aspx**

Please suggest me any good regx group for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use `<a [^>]*href=(?:'(?<href>.*?)')|(?:"(?<href>.*?)")` then the result will be stored in the named group href

Example:

```
var inputString="This is Test page <a href='test.aspx'>test page</a>";
var regex=new Regex("<a [^>]*href=(?:'(?<href>.*?)')|(?:\"(?<href>.*?)\")",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var urls=regex.Matches(inputString).OfType<Match>().Select(m =>m.Groups["href"].Value);
```

urls will be a collection of strings containing the hrefs.

Answer (score 3):

The following regex does the trick:

```
href=['"]([^'"]+?)['"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Regex on HTML, consider using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.