# How can I extract a specific text from a string?

Tags: c#

I need to find the part of the string between the two tags :

First tag `<h3><a href="/questions/`
Last tag `" class`

I'm trying to use indexof and substring but what should I do with the substring ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyString
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string htmlCode = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var myString = GetSources();

            int index = myString.IndexOf("<h3><a href=") + 11;
            string restulr = myString.Substring(index, )

            // <h3><a href="/questions/ 
            // " class
        }

        private string GetSources()
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
            {
                htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://myStringTest.com");
            }

            return htmlCode;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/a/6873932/1068246 ?

Comment: from this what do you want the output to be ?  <a href="/questions/ Last tag " class

Comment: Do you want the rest of the string starting at the index? then just leave the call as you have it. If you know the length of the rest of the string then put that in the call to substring(index, length). not to sure how much of the string you want to pull out of the parent string

Comment: You can do something like `string pattern = "<h3><a href=/questions/"; string result = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(pattern) + pattern.Length); result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("\" class");`. But that would be very fragile. Better would be to parse the HTML itself and extract the `href` attribute that way. See duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Use RegEx to separate HTML or use the [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) (HAP).