# How to find the exact value of href in <a> tag using regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a string that contains an `<a>` tag with `href` attributes. I need to find the regex which matches only **value** of hrefs.

```
<a href="http://value.com">VALUE HERE</a> <-- string to find
<a href="www.twittor.com">TWITTOR VALUE HERE</a> <-- another string to find
```

I would like to get exact `http://value.com` or `www.twittor.com`. I searched the site for an answer, many solutions were found, but they all match additional information, not the value itself.

Like this one:  [Regex to find Href value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873762/regex-to-find-href-value) matches `href="http://value.com"` and so the others.

Comment: Cue zalgo post. I can't. I'm on mobile. Someone, please.

Comment: To satisfy Jaro's yearning: [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: I got the point, but I just need to find the substring using pattern, it is not so complex task as parsing the whole HTML-document. By the way, what 'Cue zalgo post' is?

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression with a capturing group (enclosed in `()`). Then use `.exec` and grab the last item from the return value of `.exec`:

```js
const inputA = '<a href="http://value.com">VALUE HERE</a>';
const inputB = '<a href="www.twittor.com">TWITTOR VALUE HERE</a>';



const last = list => list[list.length - 1];
const extract = input => /href="(.*)"/g.exec(input);

console.log(last(extract(inputA)));
console.log(last(extract(inputB)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [native DOM parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) might be a viable alternative to a regex. Pass in the string, [`parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString), and then return the href attribute of the first child element in the body of the document returned by the parser.

```js
const str1 = '<a href="http://value.com">VALUE HERE</a>';
const str2 = '<a href="www.twittor.com">TWITTOR VALUE HERE</a>';

const parser = new DOMParser();

function getHref(parser, str) {
  return parser
    .parseFromString(str, 'text/html')
    .body.firstChild.getAttribute('href');
}

console.log(getHref(parser, str1));
console.log(getHref(parser, str2));
```

Comment: I am afraid but there is no native DOMParser in NodeJS which I use during this task. But, thanks - I will use it at client side.

Comment: I missed the node tag :) [Here are some suggestions for node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js). Side note: https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/